# IsNa Sub or Function Not Defined

Tags: vba, excel

I Know this is silly but I still can't find the answer after an hour of searching.

I'm trying to determine if a value(Customername) is an NA; I've tried the following 2 methods

```
Customername = Worksheets("Request").Range("E5")
If IsNA(Customername.value) = True Then CustomerN = 1
CustomerN = Ifna(Customername,1)
```

Both lines return errors stating "Sub of Function not defined". Whats frustrating is it recognizes the functions because it changes the capitalization, but it still breaks. I've tried dimming CustomerName as different types but doesn't seem to matter.

If you could explain the error in my thought process I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your need is to check specifically for the `#N/A` error, you can use the natively-available [ISERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) function. The caveat is that `ISERROR` will check for *any* error, not just `#N/A`.

(If you need to check specifically for `#N/A`, Pavel_V's answer is spot on.)

From the link:

```
Syntax   
ISERROR(value)  

Function  Returns TRUE if   
ISERROR   Value refers to any error value (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!).
```

You can use it like this:

```
If IsError(Customer.Value) Then
```

Additional information at [TechOnNet](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php).

Answer (score 2):

It is a worksheet function, so you have to explain this to vba by adding Application.worksheetfunction - like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Customername.value)
```